# Is there difference between transaction response and transaction receipt?

Tags: transactions, ethers.js

`Transaction response` and `transaction receipt` are **different** from one another?? *When to use which one??* in `ethers.js`

Comment: Are you refering to `TransactionResponse` and `TransactionReceipt` from ethers.js ?

Comment: ```@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers```

Comment: @Abdullah0123 see the docs for [TransactionResponse](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionResponse) and [TransactionReceipt](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionReceipt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

transactionReceipt is available only if the block is mined, it includes gasCost, gasUsed.

transactionResponse get u details like to, from, data etc. Here transaction is not mined yet.

Answer (score 4):

A `transactionResponse` object is what gets returned by awaiting an initial transactional interaction with a blockchain/contract. For this example, I'm getting a "Token" contract of my deployments and calling `transfer()` on it:

```js
const { deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat");

const [ owner, account1 ] = await ethers.getSigners(); 
await deployments.fixture(["Token"]); 
const token = await ethers.getContract("Token", owner);

const transactionResponse = await token.transfer(account1.address, 1); // initial transaction response
```

The `transactionResponse` object will hold the initial response from the local blockchain. Keep in mind that the transaction hasn't been mined yet. The object you receive back looks like that:

```js
{
  hash: '0x0032de9b9af85f72b2b1b236b69240fa09f2672b059f95600b200ae9f7360d4b',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '0x13872d79194559ec6cdd959f7c7f991f99b0073016129f77ab5c365b04b8bdb5',
  blockNumber: 2,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  confirmations: 1,
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x69a495c0', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x3b9aca00', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x97ae6180', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01bada98', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 1,
  data: '0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000070997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002',
  r: '0xd74f88e3d36e92fb32468cc4c77f2b3e72f577ffd0e9c7c274a726edb3dce6f6',
  s: '0x4b0b2648df3a3db8f2b86f64e02937970cfefd7bba59a14c0ce3f866cddd3024',
  v: 1,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 313374,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

This `transactionResponse` object has a method `wait()`, which takes a number of blocks as a parameter and returns a promise, which resolves after the number of blocks specified have been mined returning a `transactionReceipt`:

```js
const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1);
```

The `transactionReceipt` object returned looks like that:

```js
{
  to: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  contractAddress: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  gasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0xcd5d', _isBigNumber: true },
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000840000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000042000000200000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000',
  blockHash: '0x13872d79194559ec6cdd959f7c7f991f99b0073016129f77ab5c365b04b8bdb5',
  transactionHash: '0x0032de9b9af85f72b2b1b236b69240fa09f2672b059f95600b200ae9f7360d4b',
  logs: [
    {
      transactionIndex: 0,
      blockNumber: 2,
      transactionHash: '0x0032de9b9af85f72b2b1b236b69240fa09f2672b059f95600b200ae9f7360d4b',
      address: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
      topics: [Array],
      data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002',
      logIndex: 0,
      blockHash: '0x13872d79194559ec6cdd959f7c7f991f99b0073016129f77ab5c365b04b8bdb5'
    }
  ],
  blockNumber: 2,
  confirmations: 1,
  cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0xcd5d', _isBigNumber: true },
  effectiveGasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x69a495c0', _isBigNumber: true },
  status: 1,
  type: 2,
  byzantium: true,
  events: [
    {
      transactionIndex: 0,
      blockNumber: 2,
      transactionHash: '0x0032de9b9af85f72b2b1b236b69240fa09f2672b059f95600b200ae9f7360d4b',
      address: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
      topics: [Array],
      data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002',
      logIndex: 0,
      blockHash: '0x13872d79194559ec6cdd959f7c7f991f99b0073016129f77ab5c365b04b8bdb5',
      args: [Array],
      decode: [Function (anonymous)],
      event: 'Transfer',
      eventSignature: 'Transfer(address,address,uint256)',
      removeListener: [Function (anonymous)],
      getBlock: [Function (anonymous)],
      getTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      getTransactionReceipt: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `transactionReceipt` object holds all of the data pertaining to the actual mined transaction, including, but not limited to *gasUsed*, *Logs*, *Events*, and so on.

To summarize, we send transaction to blockchain and get *Response*, as soon as it gets mined we get *Receipt*